# Update Panel Not working at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

This is my code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailUser" TextMode="SingleLine" placeholder="Enter Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                ValidationGroup="Panel1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
                ControlToValidate="txtEmailUser" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="buttonBuy" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
  <br />

<asp:Button runat="server" ValidationGroup="Panel1" OnClick="buttonBuy_Click" ID="buttonBuy" width: 200px;"Text="Buy" />
```

I've tried many ways but still not working.

How can I solve it?

Comment: button is outside the UpdatePanel place it inside `contenttemplate`.

Comment: OP has `Triggers` section inside `UpdatePanel` so it should work. OP: check javascript errors in developer console. They may result in full page submit.

Comment: @Asif.Ali tnx for reply. its not working

Comment: @AlexKudryashev  tnx

Comment: @OmidTavana remove `width: 200px;` from your Button or use it like `CssClass="width: 200px;"`